# Makefile с компилятором cl

Tags: c++, makefile, компилятор

Есть проблема: я создал небольшой C++ проект который имеет 3 файла — `L3.cpp` (основной), `car.cpp` (описание заголовочного файла) и `car.h` (заголовочный файл). Далее, я пытаюсь скомпилировать данный проект с помощью компилятора `cl` и автоматизировать всё через `Makefile` (не пишите, что есть gcc, g++ и т.д. — у меня задание сделать это через компилятор cl). У меня есть трудность с изменением директории вывода. В `Makefile` все написано правильно за исключение debug — мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при вводе команды `nmake debug` у меня создавалась директория Debug и туда помещались все файлы, полученные в результате сборки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1) не следует приводить текст картинкой 2) используйте msbuild

Comment: Я по-моему ясно выразился что мне нужно сделать ИМЕННО ТАК, как я написал) Никаких msbuild нельзя :))))

Comment: В вопросе сказано, что надо использовать компилятор cl, а не что нельзя использовать msbuild. ¿Собственно раз уже вместо make начали использовать nmake, то почему бы не переключиться на msbuild?

Comment: А чем плох msbuild?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сама идея раскладывания результатов сборки по каталогам — плохая. потому и предложенное решение выглядит уродливо. но: чего просили — то и получили.

использовать не рекомендую (как, собственно, и пытаться раскладывать результаты сборок по каталогам). потому и не объясняю, что тут к чему и зачем.

```
main:
    cl /EHsc $(opts) L3.obj car.obj
    ...

...

debug:
    rm -rf $@
    mkdir -p $@
    cp -r L3 Makefile $@
    cd $@ && $(MAKE) opts="/Od /Zi"
```

Comment: ¿Почему же раскладывать результаты сборки по каталогам - плохая идея? ¿Как вы предлагаете одновременно собирать несколько конфигураций тогда? *не объясняю, что тут к чему и зачем* - а стоило бы... вот откуда там повылезали всякие cp и cd?

Comment: *Как вы предлагаете одновременно собирать несколько конфигураций тогда?* — последовательно либо параллельно. не одновременно — это физически невозможно. *а стоило бы* — так напишите.

Comment: Ребят, я знаю, что все это максимально уродливо и можно сделать намного проще, лучше и доступней) Данная задача была поставлена в университете, там очень много подобного старого шлака. Спасибо за ответ, aleksandr barakin)